# AWS SSM Parameter Store in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-ssm

I'm using AWS Elastic Beanstalk to host my application with two environments (production and staging).

I would like to store my environment variables in **AWS System Manager Parameter Store** (and AWS Secrets Manager), but I don't find simple ways to do it.

### Solutions I've considered:

#### 1) ebextensions

Creating an ebextensions to fetch the SSM parameter store variables during a deployment. But it means I'll need to perform a deployment each time I change an environment variable.

Do you have a script exemple to do it properly?

#### 2) a lambda function

Creating a lambda to fetch the SSM parameter store variables, and use `eb setenv` to set them on Elastic Beanstalk. Then, I would invoke this lambda function in a ebextension.

Is it hacky?

What would be the best solution?

Comment: got any solution for this ?

Comment: @YogeshwarTanwar I wrote a script to fetch variables from the SSM Parameter Store to a `.env` file. I run this script from a `.ebextension` during a new deployment.